# How to Add App Icon for React Native App in Google Play Internal Testing

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I created a React Native app that runs on both iOS and android. Currently I am just *testing* it on both platforms, although I am trying to figure out how to add an icon for the app for users who download it on Android. On iOS, adding an icon was easy, but for Android users, when they open their phone and look at the app on their home screen, it's just the generic Android logo.

I added a logo in the Google Play Console under "Store presence" -> "Main store listing", but it didn't work. My suspicion is that that is for when it's actually in the store.

How do I add an icon for Android users who are simply testing the app through internal testing?

Comment: If user only see generic Android logo after download, it should be the problem about your generated bundle does not changes `ic_launcher.png` in all `mipmap` folder at `/android/app/src/main/res/` .

Comment: Turns out this is the issue. Thank you! One follow up question. How do I make sure the image is the right size when shown on android? Even when I see the examples within android studio, the icon on an actual phone looks off. It is much smaller and doesn't fill the icon box on the home screen.

Comment: You can simply use the app icon generator online. You can google it and most of them have instructions for optimum size for the source image.